# What happened to Anubis's host?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Anubis was a goa'uld who ascended with the help of the ascended being Oma Desala.

I'm wondering, then, what happened to Anubis's host. We've seen that when others ascend, their clothes are left behind; would the host be similarly left behind? Or would the host have ascended along with Anubis? In that case, would the host exist as a separate ascended entity, or would it still be subsumed by Anubis, or perhaps even coexist with Anubis? If left behind, would the host survive?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Anubis does not have a host at any point when we see him in SG-1 (excepting when he possess a human after the Season 7 finale).

His human host at the time of ascension would not have been carried upwards with him simply because Anubis ascended.  That said, Anubis wanted to keep Oma thinking he was good, and Oma IS good, so it's unlikely that Anubis' host was killed.

In my mind, it's much more likely that Oma was convinced (in part) because Anubis had either allowed his host freedom (a la Tokra) and they BOTH were taught to ascend, or the human host Anubis took had no individual personality (brain dead, etc).

If Anubis allowed the host freedom, the host would have known the symbiote's thoughts and warned Oma (unless Anubis could convince him not to, which is possible).  Therefore, it's very unlikely that the host and symbiote shared ascension.

Thus, I believe that when Anubis ascended his host's body, freed of his influence, lived on.  The original personality would have re-emerged.  The host would have lived a long, full life (or been shot dead by Jaffa shortly thereafter).

Comment: Like you say, Oma would care about the host, and I doubt she'd have helped Anubis ascend if it would have caused harm to the host. I suspect this is probably the best answer we'll get.

Answer (score 5):

We know the following (Which is pulled from the [Stargate Wiki](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/Ascended_Beings)):

1. Anubis was partially ascended.
2. He was some form of energy, held together by a force field.
3. He was roughly human size.
4. Ascended being seem to be about the size they were as humans.
5. Ascension involves being turned into pure energy.

So, I'm guessing that his host/self body was turned into pure energy, and that as it was under Anubis's mind, it was all his to control. The ancients must not have checked for Goa'uld for some reason, hence why this was able to happen.

Comment: No, the ancient (Oma Desala) that helped Anubis ascend knew he was Gao'uld.  But he was able to trick her and convince her that he had changed (like the Tok'ra).  She was the same Ancient that helped Daniel Jackson ascend.  None of the other ancients were involved in helping either one ascend.  Once they discovered it, they did, however, only send Anubis part way back to mortality in part as punishment to Oma for what she had done.

Comment: The ancients don't decide if you can or can't ascend, they can help, but they can't say "No, You have to die", no wait, that was bsg, they can't say "No, you can't ascend, just because we don't like you". That, and the ancients as a whole don't particularly care what happens anyways. Well, they don't have a vested interest.

Answer (score 0):

I always figured that Anubis' host died or ascended independently of the Goa'uld, and that it was Anubis the Goa'uld who returned, taking human form, like a residual self-image.

Answer (score -1):

I would assume, that when the Goa'Uld ascended and turned into energy the host was either destroyed or just left "empty" to die shortly afterwards without the symbiote to sustain it.

Comment: Humans who have been inhabited by a Goa'uld are NOT at risk of death when the Goa'uld leaves (unless the symbiote chooses to kill them on the way out).  It is only Jaffa who lack an immune system.  Otherwise Carter, Kinthea (from Thor's Hammer's world), and Valaa wouldn't be around.

Comment: It also should be noted that one can't readily force a Goa'uld out without killing the host, but that coercion by non-surgical means can sometimes cause a Goa'uld to decide to leave.